# What is the difference between libprotobuf-dev and lib-protobuf8

Tags: package-management, application-development

I want to install `protobuf` for my cpp project, I searched `protobuf` with 
`apt-cache search protobuf`  and the result shows blow:

```
libmirprotobuf-dev - Display server for Ubuntu - protocol definition  
libmirprotobuf0 - Display server for Ubuntu - protocol implementation  
libprotobuf-dev - protocol buffers C++ library (development files)  
libprotobuf-lite8 - protocol buffers C++ library (lite version)  
libprotobuf8 - protocol buffers C++ library  
libprotoc-dev - protocol buffers compiler library (development files)  
protobuf-compiler - compiler for protocol buffer definition files  
golang-goprotobuf-dev - Protocol buffer support for the Go programming language  
libactivemq-protobuf-java - ActiveMQ Protocol Buffers Maven plugin  
libactivemq-protobuf-java-doc - ActiveMQ Protocol Buffers Maven plugin - documentation  
libdrizzledmessage-dev - Devel library containing serialized messages used with Drizzle  
libdrizzledmessage0 - Library containing serialized messages used with Drizzle
libprotobuf-c0 - Protocol Buffers C library  
libprotobuf-c0-dev - Protocol Buffers C static library and headers  
libprotobuf-java - Java bindings for protocol buffers  
mapnik-vector-tile - Vector tiles integration with mapnik - development files  
protobuf-c-compiler - protocol buffers C compiler  
python-protobuf - Python bindings for protocol buffers  
python-protobuf.socketrpc - Python socket RPC for Google protocol buffers
```

Which one should I use?

What does the "(development files)" mean?

Answer (score 0):

From [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157192/what-do-the-dev-packages-in-the-linux-package-repositories-actually-contain):

> The development files or `*-dev` packages most often contain the
>   headers related to a library's interface.

Now, regarding your installation, you do not need to worry about whether you need to install `libprotobuf-dev` or not. Just install your required package with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

and if it depends on any `*.dev` files then it will download and install them automatically.